# x86 Assembly (AT&T): How do I dynamically allocate memory to a variable at runtime?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I am trying to allocate an amount of space to a variable at runtime. I know that I can allocate a constant amount of space to a variable at compile time, for instance:

```
.data
    variable: # Allocate 100 bytes for data
        .space 100
```

However, how do I allocate a variable amount of space to a variable at runtime? For instance, allocating `%eax` bytes of space to the variable at runtime?

Comment: You can't dynamically allocate static storage.  You need to use the stack, or malloc / mmap / whatever.  (Unless you just make a huge array in the `.bss`, where you should have put this instead of `.data`, and only use however much you need.  Lazy memory allocation by the kernel makes that fine.)

Comment: @PeterCordes In other words, push the pointer of the stack down by the amount of data I want to allocate to the variable? How would I then insert data into that newly allocated space in the stack and then know how to retrieve it for later use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't dynamically allocate static storage.  You need to use the stack, or malloc / mmap / whatever (sometimes called the "heap").  (Unless you just make a huge array in the `.bss`, where you should have put this instead of `.data`, and only use however much you need.  Lazy memory allocation by the kernel makes that fine.)

You can keep a *pointer* in static storage, like C `static int *p;`, but then you need to go through the extra layer of indirection every time you access it.

A variable-sized allocation on the stack is what compilers do for `alloca`, or for C99 variable-length arrays.  Look at compiler output for how they round the allocation size up to a multiple of 16 to keep the stack aligned.  (And how they address that storage relative to the new value of the stack pointer.)