# Instantiate an array of specified size from user input in 8086 Assembly Language?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I am new to assembly and for a project, I have to prompt a user of my program to input the size of their desired array and then instantiate the array.

```
array db ? DUP(?)   ;Declare array of uninitialized size
```

Now, I am fine with creating an array of fixed length such as e.g:

```
array db 10 DUP(?)
```

However I do not know how to take the user input and create an array of their specified size.
I usually get an error on DosBox asking for a positive count for my array.

```
.code                       ;Mark start of code segment
startCode:  
extrn readsint : proc, writesint : proc     ;Make visible the external routines

mov ax, @data   ;move data segment address into the AX register
mov ds, ax  ;Load data segment address into the segment register

lea dx, stuNameNum  ;Loads effective address of string into dx
mov ah, 09h     ;Print string interrupt
int 21h

lea dx, userPrompt1 ;Print string asking user for array size
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

call readsint       ;read user size input
mov arrSize, ax     ;Store user input
```

Is their any way to do this?

Comment: You can invoke OS service to allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: How is `arrSize` defined?  You're not trying to use it in a `dup(?)` expression for the size of static storage, are you?  If so, of course that's an error.  Static stuff has to be a link-time constant, not runtime variable.  [x86 Assembly (AT&T): How do I dynamically allocate memory to a variable at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64724666)